# Create a Database of Music Files on Local Folder Using HTML 5?

Tags: html, html5-audio

I want to get music file details like 'file name', 'song name', 'size', 'artist', 'length','ratings' etc.
This is required for my website.
The user should click a button on the site and a popup should come, where he can select which folder contains the mp3 files.
Then the popup program should create the necessary data and upload it to the server.

How can I do it?
Flash?
Is there a way to do it with HTML 5? Pure HTML 5? Without using Flash?

Answer (score 0):

Flash could do some of this, and it is probably possible in javascript + html5 as it supports xmlHttpRequest, at least the file uploading part.  You can also use your preferred languages' file class to read the contents of the file and get all the details that you can.  You may have to resort to asking the user for the song name, album name, etc. you could attempt to grab the associated xml file that some programs like itunes provides, and then get all the rating data from the xml file.

Here's a link to an html 5 file upload tutorial: http://www.matlus.com/html5-file-upload-with-progress/

Comment: I made a java program, using some libraries to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I created a Java program, which collected meta data from the songs. Then via a clever GET request, I pinged the webserver to save the data.