# Index Music Files Using Flash/HTML5/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, flash, html

How can I index mp3 files on user side and create a database of file name, artist name album name etc and upload them on a server?
I would like a HTML 5 solution, although Flash or JavaScript would do.

Comment: Duplicate of your own question: [Create a Database of Music Files on Local Folder Using HTML 5? ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822682/create-a-database-of-music-files-on-local-folder-using-html-5)

Answer (score 0):

So no file uploading period? Cause if you were uploading them to a server you might find the getId3 project very useful. It does the file crawling right out of the box and all you need to do is write the PHP and SQL queries in order to write it's results to a database.

http://getid3.sourceforge.net/